# Select only last article from author

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with authors and these authors have written a bunch of articles. These articles also have a `date`. Now I only want to show the last article for every author. This is what I have so far (showing all articles).

```
SELECT authors.name as author_name,
       articles.title as article_title,
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN articles
ON authors.id = articles.author_id
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Get last date in a subquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT authors.name AS author_name, 
   (SELECT title FROM articles WHERE author_id = authors.id ORDER BY published_at DESC LIMIT 1) AS title
FROM authors;
```

or something like:

```
SELECT authors.name AS author_name, articles.title AS title
FROM authors
LEFT JOIN articles ON articles.id = (SELECT id FROM articles WHERE author_id = authors.id ORDER BY published_at DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Note that I assumed your `date` property is called `published_at`.

Answer (score 1):

*MAX* keyword will be useful to get the latest record

```
SELECT au.name as author_name, ar.title as article_title
FROM authors au INNER JOIN articles ar ON au.id = ar.author_id
INNER JOIN ( SELECT author_id, max(date_column) date FROM articles
GROUP BY articles) r ON ar.author_id = r.authorId AND ar.date_column = date
```

try this one!